# Redirect stderr panic back to terminal in go

Tags: go

I'm trying to redirect panic/standard error back to bash terminal with the following go code:

```
    if err := syscall.Dup2(-1,int(os.Stderr.Fd())); err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("Failed to redirect stderr to bash: %v",err)
    }
```

But the err gives me a "bad file descriptor", probably because of the `-1` I used in the first argument.  I chose the value `-1` because I found that `int(file.(*os.File).Fd())` returned a `-1` when `file.Close()` has been called.

As for what I'm trying to do. Elsewhere in my program, I had called a `syscall.Dup2(int(file.Fd()), int(os.Stderr.Fd()))`, which logs stderr to an external file.  But I want stderr to point to bash terminal on occasion.

https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/ Doesn't give a verbose explanation of syscall.Dup2.  I started poking around what file.Fd() returns and how it is used, but also didn't fully understand.

Can anyone tell me how to redirect stderr back to bash terminal?

Comment: `syscall.Dup2` is wrapping [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) so you should expect it to fail when the first argument is -1. BTW, I don't understand what you want to do. What if your program does not run in a terminal (e.g. has been started by some [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) job)?

Comment: Your real issue is not related to Go. It is a misunderstanding of Linux programming. You should consider reading some Linux programming book, such as [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)

Comment: I may potentially run this same code on a windows OS later into the future.  Curious if that has implications on what I asked and the answers I'll be receiving.

Comment: Of course, Linux and Windows are *very different* [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) so you should not expect them to share a common behavior.

Comment: What make you believe that your program is always started in a terminal?

Comment: Most of the time, the program won't be started from a terminal.  I have a json file with the property `debug` that is `false` by default, which causes the program to output everything to an external file.  Sometimes I might start the process from terminal, but may wish to toggle the debug mode between true and false, and have the program output stderr to terminal or a file without needing to rebuild and run the program.  That was the original intention, but if it's a bad idea, I'll use different approach.

Comment: What is your program doing? How do you start it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the original stderr somewhere before overwriting it with your first `Dup2`.  (In general, it’s a bad idea to use the `dup2` feature of closing the target, since it can’t report errors therefrom.)  Then you can `Dup2` *that* back to `int(os.Stderr.Fd())` (aka 2).

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me how to redirect stderr back to bash terminal?

**In general, that is impossible**, because a Unix program can be started (or run) *without* any terminal. For example, it could be started by a [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) job, or thru some `at` or `ssh` command, etc. Think also of your program being run with [redirections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) or in a [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)), or of your program being run in a server (e.g. inside a data center); then it is likely to not have any terminal.

The common practice is for the user of your program to perhaps redirect `stderr` (and probably *not* to a terminal, but more likely to some file). Your user would use its [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) for that purpose (e.g. run `yourprogram 2> /tmp/errorfile`; read the [documentation of `bash` about redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html))

[Terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) are quite complex stuff. You could read the [TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page. See also [pty(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html) and [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html). The usual way to handle terminals (on Unix) is by using the [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library (which has been wrapped as [goncurses](https://github.com/rthornton128/goncurses) in Go).

> Elsewhere in my program, I had called a syscall.Dup2(int(file.Fd()), int(os.Stderr.Fd())), which logs stderr to an external file.

That is really a bad idea. Your user expects his/her [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) to stay the same (and would have redirected the `stderr` in his/her shell if so needed). Conventionally, you should not mess that [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) in your program (and leave them to what they are).

A [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) is some small positive-or-zero index (into the file descriptor table of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))). System calls like [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) are expecting valid file descriptors, and Go's `syscall.Dup2` is just wrapping that [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html).

On Linux, you can query the file descriptor table of some process of pid 1234 by looking into the `/proc/1234/fd/` directory. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more.

If you are absolutely certain that your program *is* running in a terminal, you might open `/dev/tty` to get it. See [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) for more. However, I don't recommend doing that (because you'll better design your program to be runnable *outside* of any terminal).

You may want to read some Linux programming book, such as [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/).

For logging purposes, Go provides its [log](https://golang.org/pkg/log/) package. See also [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) and the [`log/syslog`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/syslog/) package of Go.

PS. I don't know Windows, but I believe it also can start programs without any terminal, e.g. as a [background process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_process). So even on Windows I would try to avoid doing that (redirection of stderr to a terminal).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but `syscall.Dup2(0,int(os.Stderr.Fd()))` returns panic stderr back to terminal.

My understanding of the linux operating system is weak.  So I don't understand the significance of `0` in this context and the linux documentation.

Also, I haven't attempted this approach on a windows machine, so not sure what will happen there.  I hope other people give better answers.

Comment: In that context (of using [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html)) the 0 is the file descriptor of standard input, i.e. `STDIN_FILENO`. See also [stdin(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdin.3.html)

Comment: In some cases, descriptors 0 and 2 start out equivalent, so it’s serving as an accidental backup of the sort I said you needed.